# Does $AB=(AB)^{\ast}$ and $A=A^{\ast}$ implies $B=B^{\ast}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Suppose that we have $AB=(AB)^{\ast}$ and  $A=A^{\ast}$, does this implies that $B=B^{\ast}$? ($A^{\ast}$ is the Hermitian adjoint of $A$.)

I have a feeling that they might not be equal in general. If $B\ne B^{\ast}$ then what condition(s) do we need to add in order that $B=B^{\ast}$? $A,B\ne 0$.

**Edit**:  According to the comment, it is not true after all. However, I am more interested in what minimal conditions do we add to $B$ to make the statement true. I was reading a Physics text and it claimed $B=B^{\ast}$. As we all know, Physics books tend to omit important assumption.

Comment: Consider the case $A=0$.

Comment: @user1551 I forgot to rule out the trivial solution, my bad.

Comment: You may also pick a random Hermitian matrix $C$, a random invertible Hermitian matrix $A$ and define $B=A^{-1}C$.

Comment: @user1551 Thank you very much, so it's not true after all. I've edited my question a bit to match what I was really looking for, would you mind helping me?

Comment: Why don't you quote the passage from the book?

Comment: A quick note: On finite-dimensional vector spaces, simply diagonalise $A$ and you'll see the answer. In particular, if $A$ is also invertible, then $B$ is Hermitian if and only if $AB=BA$.

Answer (score 0):

From the information given we can calculate: $AB = (AB)^* = B^* A^* = B^* A$. To be able to conclude that $B^*=B$, we would need to be able to invert $A$, which would give us: $B^* = A B A^{-1}$. And then we would need that $B = A B A^{-1}$ for which I have forgotten the name.

Comment: The name is "$A$ and $B$ commute" :)

Comment: @s.harp that would work, but there is also a name for the weaker condition IIRC.

Comment: This is not a weaker condition, $B=ABA^{-1} \iff (BA-AB)A^{-1}=0 \iff (BA-AB)=0$

Comment: If we suppose $A$ only has a right inverse then the condition is weaker

Comment: @s.harp I stand corrected :). I think I am confused with $ABA^\dagger$ or something similar.